# JQuery how to traverse to <form> from <button> inside, with <div> in between

Tags: jquery, forms, html, input, traversal

Alright guys, so I have the below structure, 10 times, which means 10 forms.
`$('button')` will handle event for any button, as you know.

```
<div>
  <form ...>
    <div><button type='button'>Submit</button></div>
    <div><input /></div>
    <div><input /></div>
    <div><input /></div>
    <div><input /></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Using JQuery only, and its traversing methods only, how do I get the `<form>` from `$(this)` when I click on the button??

I used a mix of parent(), prev(), etc before but couldn't get it.
For example, `$(this).closest('form').nodeName` gives "undefined" in alert popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
  $(':button').closest('form')
```

UPDATE

```
$(':button').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('form').attr('class'));
});
```

Comment: sorry I need to traverse from $(this) when I clicked on the button.

Comment: Oh it works! you are the man!
$('button').click(function(){
 alert($(this).closest('form').attr('method')); }
gives "POST"!

Comment: $('button').closest('form') works too!
what's the difference?
Thanks man beforehand!

Answer (score 1):

this will definetly work:

```
 $('button').click(function(){
     alert($(this).closest('form').attr('id'));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$('button').parents('form:first').get(0).nodeName;
```

like this

```
$('button').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parents('form:first').get(0).nodeName);
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gmyjt/1/)

**UPDATE:**

you can simple `submit` it like this

```
$('button').click(function(){
     $(this).parents('form:first').get(0).submit();
});​
```

Comment: ya it gives 'FORM' in popup but I need to use it to perform submit() or attr(). it doesnt work. get(0) returns an object only.

Comment: what is the point of getting the nodeName when already know it is `form` ?

Comment: @charlietfl i alert this because he mentioned that he tried alerting it

Comment: i have many forms and button in each. When I click a button I wanna submit the corresponding form. I can send the id of the submit as argument and perform sth to get the corresponding form but it is not elegant

Comment: nope it doesn't work in chrome.. problem is with the get(0) i think.
as someone told me it returns the node type

Comment: oh ya it's working! But somehow the serialize() method which I actually need to use, doesn't work. I gave name to all elements